# ¿Como puedo mostrar el numero de teléfono en un marcador y pulsar para llamar?

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps

Necesito que en el marcador salga el teléfono de los talleres en el cuadro de información y que el usuario pueda pulsarlo y llamar.
 Este es el código donde voy posicionando los marcadores en el mapa traigo los marcadores desde una Api Rest con toda su información con un AsyncTask

Aqui es donde llamo al AsynTask

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;


        new MapsActivity.PeticionTask().execute(new String[]{TallerPrincipalActivity.linkCampico+"/talleres","GET"});
    }

//Y en el PostExecute es donde cargo los puntos en el mapa recorriendo un //arrayList 

 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Taller> s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);


            Log.e("mapas",""+talleres);
            for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++){

              //  Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, ""+s.get(i).getLatitud()+" "+s.get(i).getLongitud(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                LatLng punto1 = new LatLng(s.get(i).getLatitud(), s.get(i).getLongitud());


                Marker puntos = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(punto1)

                        .title(s.get(i).getNombre()+"  "+i)


                        .snippet(s.get(i).getDireccion()));

                puntos.showInfoWindow();

            }



        }
    }
```

Comment: En tu objeto s guardar el numero?

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez si se guarda el teléfono y demas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a tu marker asignarle un objeto con `setTag()`

```
 Marker puntos = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(s)
                    .title(s.get(i).getNombre()+"  "+i)
                    .snippet(s.get(i).getDireccion()));
        puntos.setTag(s);
```

Debes sobreescribir el metodo `setOnMarkerClickListener`:

```
 nMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            TuObjeto s= (TuObjeto) marker.getTag();
            String numero = s.getTelefono(); //suponiendo que asi se llama el atributo
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + numero));
            startActivity(intent);
            
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Recuerda que debes tener en tu `Manifest.xml` el permiso

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Y depende de tu version android pedirlo en tiempo de ejecucion

Comment: Cuando pongo el .setTag se me marca en rojo y sale este mensaje  Incompatible types.
Required:
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker
Found:
void

Comment: a mi me funciono copiando tu codigo, quiza deberias pones mas datos de tu clase para ver si otro error

Comment: Añadi mas codigo a la pregunta el onMapReady y el PostExecute entero

Comment: @ÁlvaroGironaCutillas edite mi respuesta puedes probarla